# How to resolve this error? I cant install this (@ramonak/react-excel) package for edit Imported Excel

Tags: reactjs

PS C:\Users\Dev03\Downloads\usermanagement (1)\usermanagement> npm install --save @ramonak/react-excel
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: usermanagement@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from @ramonak/react-excel@1.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@ramonak/react-excel
npm ERR!   @ramonak/react-excel@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Dev03\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dev03\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-30T09_27_18_520Z-debug.log

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try reading the error message? Did you try using a search engine to help you to understand what the error message means? Stack Overflow doesn't exist to do basic debugging and troubleshooting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
npm install --save @ramonak/react-excel --legacy-peer-deps
```